# Trimming or Stripping end of line or begining of line chararchers Python

Tags: python-3.x, string, arduino

I do not use Stack overflow very often so I hope that my formatting doesn't piss to many of you off?
Thanks or any input!
DB

I am attempting to understand how to strip initial and end of line characters sent from Arduino serial (Arduino Console)port from a sketch reading BME680 Temp Humi Sensor.  The output from the Arduino to the Serial port looks like this:

[image]

Utilizing this code: Below

```
`import serial

# -- update your project info --

#serial port of Arduino
#on windows it will be "COM5" format
#on mac it will be "/dev/cu.usbmodemxxx" format
 arduino_port = "COM4"
 baud = 9600 #arduino uno runs at 9600 baud
 fileName="BME680-data-2020_11_20.csv" 
 samples = 10 #how many samples do you want to collect?
 print_labels = False #do you want to print out line ids to serial?

      # -- no need to edit beyond this line!--
  ser = serial.Serial(arduino_port, baud)
  print("Connected to Arduino port:" + arduino_port)
   file = open(fileName, "a")
    print("Created file")

  line = 0

 while line <= samples:
     # incoming = ser.read(9999)
     # if len(incoming) > 0:
  if print_labels:
    if line==0:
        print("Printing Column Headers")
    else:
        print("Line " + str(line) + ": writing...")
     getData=str(ser.readline())
     data=getData[0:][:-2]
     print(data)

     file = open(fileName, "a")

     file.write(data + "\n") #write data with a newline
     line = line+1

 print("Data collection complete!")
  file.close()
```

`The return in the Spyder Console looks like this.

> Connected to Arduino port:COM4
> Created file
> b'BME680 test\r
> b'69.04,840.89,27.96,0.00,5293.06\r
> b'69.19,840.89,27.90,223.58,5293.06\r
> b'69.40,840.85,27.77,229.48,5294.32\r
> b'69.53,840.85,27.71,233.04,5293.69\r
> b'69.58,840.85,27.76,233.20,5294.32\r
> b'69.64,840.83,27.76,233.70,5294.96\r
> b'69.66,840.83,27.76,234.36,5294.96\r
> b'69.67,840.81,27.73,234.36,5294.96\r
> b'69.67,840.83,27.73,234.19,5294.96\r
> b'69.69,840.81,27.74,236.37,5295.60\r
> Data collection complete!

I would like to understand how to remove the b' and the \r\ on either end of the string.

If there is a way to send cleaner strings to the Arduino Console I would like to here that as well.

DB

Comment: the `strip()` method cleans up most of that: `line.strip()`. For python 3.9, you can also use `.removesuffix()` and `.removeprefix()`. Or if all lines have that format you can use `line[2:-2]` to remove the beginning and ending of a line.

Comment: `str.strip("\r")`, `str.replace("\r", "")` etc should work